# How to disable previous date using datetimepicker plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I want to disable previous `date` and show only present and future dates. I need only `datetimepicker`. Not `datepicker`. I applied this method

```
$(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datetimepicker({ minDate: 0});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following options:

```
//beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, //optional
constrainInput: true, // restrict keyboard input
minDate: '+1d' // set minimum date to tomorrow
```